# C# Reading, Storing, and Combining Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on an RS232 communication effort but have been running into issues with the some of the arrays I am handling.

In the example below I am sending out a "Command" with the intent to read and store the first 4 bytes of the command in a new array called "FirstFour". For every loop execution that is run I also want to convert the integer "i" to a Hex value. I then intend to combine the "FirstFour" and "iHex" arrays into a new array noted as "ComboByte". Below is my code so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
private void ReadStoreCreateByteArray()
    {
        byte[] Command = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x05, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //Send Command
            comport.Write(Command, 0, Command.Length);

            //Read response and store in buffer
            int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[bytes];
            comport.Read(Buffer, 0, bytes);

            //Create 4 byte array to hold first 4 bytes out of Command
            var FirstFour = Buffer.Take(4).ToArray();

            //Convert i to a Hex value
            byte iHex = Convert.ToByte(i.ToString());

            //Combine "FirstFour" and "iHex" into a new array
            byte [] ComboByte = {iHex, FirstFour[1], FirstFour[2], FirstFour[3], First Four[4]};
            comport.Write(ComboByte, 0, ComboByte.Length);

         }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `comport.Read(Buffer, 0, bytes);` it is **essential** to handle the return method from `Read` correctly, btw.

Comment: What is `respBuffer`?

Comment: Is the ComboByte initialization correct?  Shouldn't FirstFour be indexed from 0-3 and not 1-4?

Comment: `byte iHex = Convert.ToByte(i.ToString())` should just be `byte iHex = (byte)i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are zero based, so...

```
byte [] ComboByte = {iHex, FirstFour[0], FirstFour[1], FirstFour[2], First Four[3]};
```

...should give you the first 4 elements of FirstFour.

Comment: Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you **need** to handle the return value from `Read` operations. The following pattern should work fine for a range of APIs, including `SerialPort`, `Stream`, etc:

```
static void ReadExact(SerialPort port, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int read;
    while(count > 0 && (read = port.Read(buffer, offset, count)) > 0)
    {
        count -= read;
        offset += read;
    }
    if (count != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
}
```

So: you have a method that can read a reliable number of bytes - you should then be able to re-use a single buffer and populate it sequentially:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    //...
    buffer[0] = (byte)i;
    ReadExact(port, buffer, 1, 4);
}
```

The `BytesToRead` property is largely useless except for deciding whether to read synchronously or asynchronously, as it doesn't tell you whether more data is *imminent*. With your existing code there is no guarantee you will have at least 4 bytes.